# Notify Hubspot associations changes

Tags: api, notifications, associations, hubspot

I have created a private app which notify our platform about contacts, companies and deals changes by configuring a subscription in webhooks.

How can i notify associations changes too? For example, notify when a company is associated with a contact. I think it's not possible with the webhooks API.

I need these notifications in order to keep both platforms in sync.

I have configured a private app but it is not possible to configure a subscription in webhooks for associations

Answer (score 0):

Now i have a solution.

I have created a calculated property (named "version") which count all registers associated with an object which have "Record Id". Each time an association is created / deleted, this property modifies its value.

Then i have subscrive the change event of this property "version" on webhooks (private app). Each time an association is created / deleted, a notification is sended because the change in the total value of "version".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

HubSpot associations are challenging to work with because they aren't supported with Webhooks, can't be searched using the `/search` endpoint, and can't be sorted like objects.

One option is to build a polling sync to pull the latest state of your associations continuously. This guide explains how:

https://blog.sequin.io/building-a-sync-on-hubspots-api/